# Adding variances of a variable

Tags: statistics, variance

I have the average variance of a stock's daily return over a year and I want to know whether or not I can times this number by 252 (number of trading days in a year) to find the yearly variance. My prediction is that I can because you can add the variances of two independent random variables and one could argue that the return of the stock on one day does not affect the return on the next (in theory). Am I correct? If not how can I get the yearly variance from this data?

EDIT: another reason I think I'm correct is that you can multiply the mean return and get the average return for the year so why not variance too.

Comment: If the daily changes truly are independent, this should work.  But if, say, there is strong correlation between the days, it won't (consider an asset that mean reverts strongly).  there's no way to predict the correlation from the list of daily variances.

Comment: Thanks! Is this also the case for daily covariance between two stocks (ie multiply daily covariance matrix by 252 to get yearly)?

Comment: Sure, and for the same reason.  Real stock data is messy.  If, say, you have a REIT or equivalent then profits are paid out in dividends, so the share price can only move within a fairly tight band.  But even non-dividend paying stocks have price action which does not follow theoretical ideals.